# C function call without bracket

Tags: c, function, mingw

Here is a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Display something\n");
    fflush stdout;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with msys2 mingw-w64 gcc version 7.3.0 and option -Wall and everything works fine, just as if the 5th line was `fflush(stdout);`.

I tried to reproduce such a call with my own function, but I get the perfectly expected error

```
src/main.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
src/main.c:5:18: error: expected ';' before 'parameter'
  custom_function parameter;
                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

So, what happens with the `fflush` function? Can somebody explain me? Do you have the same behavior with other C compilers?

Comment: no, no : `fflush stdout`, and I am asking why it works.

Comment: related to the fact that fflush is a builtin, maybe even a macro

Comment: I cannot reproduce on `linux`, it might be `mingw` thing.

Comment: In principle, the `flush` not followed by `(` maps to a function pointer.  But it isn't immediately obvious how `stdin` maps to be a legitimate continuation.  Have you looked at the output from the C preprocessor?  (`gcc -E`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's see preprocessor output (using MinGW, and `gcc -E test.c` command line):

```
   fflush 
# 5 "test.c" 3
          (&(* _imp___iob)[1])
# 5 "test.c"
                ;
```

as you see `stdout` is a macro which expands to `(&(* _imp___iob)[1])` with parentheses.

so the compiler uses those parentheses and the syntax is okay.

But that's only because of macro magic, and the fact that most macros are protected by parentheses to avoid side-effects with other tokens (operator precendence for instance)

You can reproduce that without any includes with this simple code:

```
#define arg ("hello")

void f(const char *x)
{
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    f arg;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course this is bad practice, confuses IDEs (and humans), so just don't do it.

Comment: Looking at the preprocessor output explains it — it wasn't obvious.  It's a curious side-effect of "parentheses around expressions in macros".  That's an older pattern of '`stdout` as a macro'; modern Linux, in particular, makes `stdout` a regular object.  So does macOS.

Comment: Something new in the C tag, for once :) tagging question as "mingw" since it's somehow specific and reproducible as-is only on that platorm

Comment: well played ^^ I was so concentrated on fflush that I didn't think about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question:

[image]

See Jean-François Fabre's answer.
there's an oddity in the wording in the
standard (and I make no claim that it's anything more than that).

C99 7.19.1 says:

> The header  declares three types, several macros, and
>   many functions for performing input and output.
>
> ...
>
> The macros are
>
> ...
>
> stderr
>   stdin
>   stdout
>
> which are expressions of type "pointer to FILE" that point to the
>   FILE objects associated, respectively, with the standard error,
>   input, and output streams.

As Keith Thompson have said long ago
In context, this says they're macros -- but the descriptions of all
the other macros use the phrase "which expands to".  For stderr,
stdin, and stdout, it says they *are* expressions (which, if they're
macros, isn't strictly correct).

If they're allowed to be, say, declared objects rather than macros,
then 7.19.1p1 should be changed to allow for these declarations, and
the description of stderr, stdin, and stdout shouldn't be part of the
page-long run-on sentence.

More plausibly, if they *are* required to be macros, the phrase "which
are expressions" should be changed to "which expand to expressions".

They are not guaranteed to be macros. In your case though,
you got lucky the macro expands to an expression with protection brackets.
A sheer example of evil macro hiding the actual content.